# Xamarin.Forms Add a GestureRecognizer to an Image in a ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add a tap gesture to an Image within a ListView

The following **Image** renders correctly in the ListView without the **Image.GestureRecognizers** section, but with it, the ListView does not render anything at all (no error message).  **To clarify this, there is also a Label in the ListView and that does not render either.**

```
<Image x:Name="newsImage" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding Imageurllarge}">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" 
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
```

I took this from - http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/gestures/ (assume this example is for not listview image, but assumed it should work within a listview).

Also (as per comment suggestion)

```
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer 
      Command="{Binding TapCommand}" 
      CommandParameter="newsImage" />
```

Does not seem to fair any better.

If anyone has an example of how to add this in the code behind (without a viewmodel is fine) then that will do.

Comment: note that `TappedCallback` is obsolete, use `Command`

Comment: Tried Command variant, same result.

Comment: It is specifically the image that has to be tapped? ListView selection change event doesn't cut it?

Comment: I can possibly rework things to avoid this, but should I really have to? Am I asking something out of the ordinary i.e. should you never use ListView and have separate clickable images?

Comment: WickedW did you ever get this issue sorted out ?

Comment: @EoinCampbell Campbell, sorry I have not looked at this for a long time, will review answer below when get chance ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DataTemplate in the ListView and inside the DataTemplate have a Grid then add the UI elements. In the given sample, I am showing the Name, contact number and Image, I have used the GestureRecognizers on the Image. Try this:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" >             
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell Height="75">
        <Grid Padding="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="user_img.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Font="16" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Font="12" Text="{Binding Number}"  LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>

            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"  Grid.Column="2" Source="add.png" Aspect="AspectFill">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                    Command="{Binding AddCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Number}" />
                  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>        
        </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>    
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with `TapGestureRecognizer` in uses like this one by specifying it in XAML with its own `x:Name` attribute, then adding a tap handler in code.

Example markup:

```
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="tapImage" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

Then in code something like:

```
this.tapImage.Tapped += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
... // Do whatever is wanted here
}
```

The handler need not necessarily be marked `async`, it is just common for my uses that something async is happening in there, like a confirm dialog or scanning a bar code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also attach a gesture recognizer to an image inside a listview.  The gesture recognizer can bind to a command in a view model

```
     <ListView x:Name="ExampleList" SeparatorVisibility="None" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="{Binding HeightRequest}"
                     HasUnevenRows="True"
                     CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding FeedItems}"
                      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                      RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                      IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate  >
              <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                      <Label Text="{Binding TimeAgo}" FontSize="8"></Label>
                      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="Accept.png" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="45" IsVisible="{Binding IsAccepted, Converter={StaticResource inverse}}">
                          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource sampleViewModel}, Path=AcceptCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RequestID}" />
                          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>                          
                      </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                  </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
```